# Cumulative Total filtered by a range date to calculate the variation between the period selected. PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, slider, cumulative-sum

I have a table that in the columns has a vendor list, then I have total transactions, previous year total transactions, and a year to date total column, my goal is to built a column that shows the variation between the YEAR TO DATE COLUMN and THE PREVIOUS YEAR COLUMN but my issue is that I have a slicer date filter so I need that the previous year calculation will be accumulative and not total in a dynamic way, is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

I tried using DATEADD, DATTESYTD together but it shows me the total of last year not the range that I specified on the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `LastYear` this way:

```
Last Year = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('cost-management-export'[costInBillingCurrency]), 
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(
        'Calendar'[Date].[Date])

)
```

Then use a Line Chart this way:

[image]